# How to work out theta value of my data for use in negative binomial GLM?

Tags: r, glm

I am trying to do a GLM for a count dataset, and have found that my data is overdispersed and so, not suitable to use a poisson GLM on. I am aware that I have to use a negative binomial GLM instead, which requires a theta value. However, when I try to run a summary of my model I get a series of errors below and it can't find the theta value. Any help on this would be appreciated. I will put a summary of my dataset and my code used to produce a summary of the model and the errors below.

Dataset summary:

[image]

The data used for the GLM is total (Count data) and treatment (which is a letter representing different treatments eg. C, M, F)

Code used to produce theta:

```
    summary(m1 <- glm.nb(Total ~ Treatment, data = twohour))
```

Output of this code with errors at the bottom:

[image]

Any help with producing a theta value would be greatly appreciated. Thanks in advance.

As requested, the summary and model outputs as text:

summary:

```
> summary(twohour)


  Treatment        |     Length         |        ID          |   Block1          Block2       |   Fertility      |    Notes         |       Total      
 Length:252   |       Length:252     |     Min.   : 1.00   | Min.   :  0.0   Min.   :  0.00   Min.   :0.0000   Length:252         Min.   :  0.0  
 Class :character   Class :character   1st Qu.:10.00   1st Qu.:125.8   1st Qu.: 39.50   1st Qu.:1.0000   Class :character   1st Qu.:172.2  
 Mode  :character   Mode  :character   Median :19.50   Median :154.0   Median :104.50   Median :1.0000   Mode  :character   Median :263.0  
                                       Mean   :19.89   Mean   :143.5   Mean   : 94.66   Mean   :0.9683                      Mean   :238.1  
                                       3rd Qu.:30.00   3rd Qu.:179.2   3rd Qu.:146.00   3rd Qu.:1.0000                      3rd Qu.:309.5  
                                       Max.   :40.00   Max.   :227.0   Max.   :228.00   Max.   :1.0000                      Max.   :434.0
```

model output:

```
> Call: glm.nb(formula = Total ~ Treatment, data = twohour, init.theta =
> 2055605.705, 
>     link = log)
> 
> Deviance Residuals: 
>     Min       1Q   Median       3Q      Max  
> -23.001   -4.624    1.650    4.567   12.571  
> 
> Coefficients:
               Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)     (Intercept)   5.577987   0.009846 566.534  < 2e-16 *** TreatmentC   -0.102625   0.014394  -7.130 1.01e-12 *** TreatmentF   -0.154580   0.014396 -10.737  < 2e-16 *** TreatmentF30 -0.298972   0.019920 -15.008  < 2e-16 *** TreatmentM   -0.158733   0.014613 -10.862  < 2e-16 ***
 TreatmentM30 -0.044795   0.013992  -3.201  0.00137 **  TreatmentMxF
 -0.105191   0.014211  -7.402 1.34e-13 ***
 --- Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1
 
 (Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(2055606) family taken to
 be 1)
 
    Null deviance: 15127  on 251  degrees of freedom Residual deviance: 14799  on 245  degrees of freedom AIC: 16542

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1

Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width,
3L,  :    invalid 'nsmall' argument In addition: Warning messages: 

1: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace =control$trace  :   iteration limit reached 

2: In sqrt(1/i) : NaNs produced 

3: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  :   iteration limit reached 

4: In sqrt(1/i) : NaNs produced
```

Comment: Can you please post your `summary()` output and model output as *text* rather than as screenshots?  Screenshots are un-searchable and inaccessible to people using screen readers ...

Comment: I have done so, please tell me if this helps.

Comment: Hmmm. Is there a way you can cut and paste leaving the formatting (tabs or spaces) intact?

Comment: I have now done so I hope this helps.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

**tl;dr** I suspect this is driven by outliers, especially (??) some zero values that are inconsistent with the rest of the data set.  If the zero values aren't errors/weird cases, you might consider a *zero-inflated* model ...???

We probably need your data to know for sure what's going on. Here's what I can gather so far:

- some aspects of your results look like *underdispersion* (ridiculously large theta estimate, "iteration limit reached" warnings ...
- ... yet I agree that your data seem to be *overdispersed* (large ratio of residual deviance to residual df; range from 0 to 434 with a mean of 238)
- ... the extreme range of the deviance residuals (-23 to +12) suggest outliers (the deviance residuals are essentially on the log scale ...)

I can get most of the way by constructing a data set that's mostly Poisson, but with a few extreme outliers:

```r
n <- 252     ## total number of obs
ng <- 7      ## number of groups/treatments
mu <- exp(6)    ## mean response
   ## NOTE: this doesn't match your data, I did it accidentally,
   ##  but it does reproduce the errors.
set.seed(101)
dd <- data.frame(
    ## mostly Poisson, but with 2 values at the min and max values
    y = c(rpois(n-4, lambda=mu), rep(c(0,434), each=2)),
    f = factor(rep(1:ng, length.out = n))
)
summary(dd)
library(MASS)
m2 <- glm.nb(y~f, data = dd)
```

(the zero values look like the largest problem. I can reproduce the problem with 2 (but not 1) zero outliers, with the rest of the data Poisson with a large mean ...)

```
Warning messages:
1: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  :
  iteration limit reached
2: In sqrt(1/i) : NaNs produced
3: In theta.ml(Y, mu, sum(w), w, limit = control$maxit, trace = control$trace >  :
  iteration limit reached
4: In sqrt(1/i) : NaNs produced
```

Results:

```r
Call:
glm.nb(formula = y ~ f, data = dd, init.theta = 12474197.56, 
    link = log)

Deviance Residuals: 
     Min        1Q    Median        3Q       Max  
-28.1363   -0.4887    0.0444    0.7153    3.4771  

Coefficients:
              Estimate Std. Error z value Pr(>|z|)    
(Intercept)  6.0005206  0.0082958 723.319  < 2e-16 ***
f2           0.0006192  0.0117302   0.053  0.95790    
f3           0.0015129  0.0117276   0.129  0.89736    
f4          -0.0328793  0.0118297  -2.779  0.00545 ** 
f5          -0.0195274  0.0117898  -1.656  0.09766 .  
f6           0.0068583  0.0117120   0.586  0.55816    
f7          -0.0087784  0.0117579  -0.747  0.45531    
---
Signif. codes:  0 ‘***’ 0.001 ‘**’ 0.01 ‘*’ 0.05 ‘.’ 0.1 ‘ ’ 1

(Dispersion parameter for Negative Binomial(12474198) family taken to be 1)

    Null deviance: 1837.2  on 251  degrees of freedom
Residual deviance: 1820.0  on 245  degrees of freedom
AIC: 3795.6

Number of Fisher Scoring iterations: 1
```

> Error in prettyNum(.Internal(format(x, trim, digits, nsmall, width, 3L,  :
> invalid 'nsmall' argument

A little digging shows that this particular error is caused because the standard error of the theta estimate can't be computed (it's `NaN`) ...

Looking at the diagnostics (`plot(m2)`) shows the outliers clearly:

[image: diagnostic plot for NB: observations 249 and 250 are big outliers]

The following works fine (more or less: it gives ridiculous `theta` estimates because the data are *not* overdispersed once zero-inflation is accounted for).

```r
library(pscl)
zeroinfl(y~f, dist="negbin",data = dd)
```

Comment: Thank you very much for your help - the 0s are not outliers but biological 0s where individuals haven’t produced offspring based on what treatment they were subject to. I will look in to 0 inflated models. Thanks again,

Comment: If this solves your problem (see addition) you are encouraged to click the check-mark to accept it ...